# Comparing distribution of continuous data and binned data that are compositional

Tags: regression, censoring, compositional-data, finite-population, interval-censoring

### The Data

I have a list of N ∼ 6700 population members who have a condition and are labeled with age in whole years and biological sex.

For the parent population, I have

1. The total number of each sex (∼1e6 each).
2. A [population pyramid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_pyramid) labeled in percentages to one decimal place.

I want to test the hypothesis that the population members have experienced the condition randomly.

### Exploratory Result

As a first pass, I performed a brute-force bootstrap simulation of N population members drawn from a multinomial distribution based on the population proportions. This simulation suggests that the observed numbers are *very* unlikely for certain age groups in some systematic ways related to sex.

### The Question

What are the appropriate models for rigorous hypothesis testing in this situation? The binned percentages represent censored data, which I have never worked with before. From having worked with count data in the past, I'm aware that [compositional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compositional_data) effects are present in this system. Also, I read that doing regression on binned data invokes the issue of [censoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Censoring_(statistics)), specifically interval censoring.

On the other hand, the situation does not seem too out of the ordinary. I have some bins and some unbinned data. I want to see if the unbinned data is from the same population as what was put in the bins. Are there standard methods?